# Join a table to itself using an array column?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I have a table:

```
id        integer
status_id integer
children  integer[]
```

How do I write a query to join the table to itself on children and find all records where (all children items have status_id 2) & the item has status of 1?

In addition should children be indexed and with what index?

Edit: Based on **krokodilko** answer I think the query may be:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.status_id, every(c.status_id = 2) AS all_children_status_2
    FROM positions p
    JOIN positions c
    ON c.id = ANY (p.children)
    GROUP BY p.id, p.status_id
) sub
WHERE all_children_status_2 IS TRUE AND status_id = 1;
```

Edit 2:
Please note I have found in my reading that the array columns should use a GIN or GIST index. However unfortunately postgres does not use these indexes when using ANY. These mean that while the above query works it is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/arrays.html) operator:


Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2540d/1

```
CREATE TABLE parent(
  id int,
  child int[]
);

INSERT INTO parent VALUES(1, '{2,4,5}');

CREATE TABLE child(
  id int
);

INSERT INTO child VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM parent p
JOIN child c
ON c.id = any( p.child );

| id | child | id |
|----|-------|----|
|  1 | 2,4,5 |  2 |
|  1 | 2,4,5 |  4 |
|  1 | 2,4,5 |  5 |
```

---

> In addition should children be indexed and with what index?

Yes - if children table is huge (more than a few hundreds/thousands rows).

```
CREATE INDEX some_name ON child( id )
```